# Compiler errors when trying to overload operator+= for an enum

Tags: c++, boost, enums, operator-overloading, boost-icl

I'm having some problems trying to overload the += operator for an enum I've defined within a namespace. I shouldn't need to actually use the operator, however, a library I'm using (boost::icl) requires that the += operator is defined for the data I'm storing within the interval map. Whenever I try to compile the code below, I get the following compiler error using Intel C++:

```
error : enum "test::events" has no member "operator+="
```

Any suggestions?

test.h:

```
namespace test {

    enum events {
        SHUTIN = 0,
        ACTIVE,
        RECOMPLETE,
        CTI,
        RTP
    };

   events & events::operator+= (const events &rhs);

}; // end namespace test
```

test.cpp:

```
test::events & test::events::operator+= (const test::events &rhs) {
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You can't overload `operator+=` for enums.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I couldn't find anything online that explicitly said so... Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Even if you could, you cannot invent member functions for types that don't already have them.

Comment: @juanchopanza Really? It would follow (at least to me) that if you could define operators for user-defined data structures, that you should be able to overload or create new operators for the existing types. TIL. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You would have to declare those member operators inside the definition of the user defined type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free function:

```
events & operator+= (events &lhs, const events &rhs);
```

(tested with GCC 4.8, if Intel C++ rejects it I'd think it's a bug)